# Getting span content in another div

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get the html content of span with id of pageNum when I click on the button with id of id1 in Jquery?

In other words, is there any way to go to the closest "pagination" div and get "pageNum" from there?

```
<div class='pagination'>
    <div class='pagination-tools'>
        <span class='pageNum'>2</span>
    </div>
</div>

</div>

<div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <button id="id1"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#2').on('click', function () {
    var html = $('.pageNum').html();
});
```

Per my declarative suggestion comment:

```
$('#2').on('click', function () {
    var html = $('[data-id="' + this.id + '"]').html();
});
```

Comment: Sorry it is not id of pageNum it is the class my bad!

Comment: `$('#2')` is the same as `document.getElementById('2')`

Comment: Class is applied `.pageNum` instead of `#pageNum`

Comment: But I have many tabs with the same format of divs of "pagination", "pagination-tools" and "pageNum", and I need the closest one (current page)!

Comment: Notice you don't have anything with `id="2"`, so I'm not sure if your question is wrong or you just omitted it from your example.

Comment: Now you don't make any sense.

Comment: So there is no way to go to the closest "pagination" div and get "pageNum" from there?

Comment: Don't do it that way - create some declarative reference like `<span class='pageNum' data-id="2">2</span>`